# Retrieve specific rows without using rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Since I cant use `rownum` in the query, how can i use `rowid` to get result from 2nd row until 4th row using `rowid` or other possible solution apart from `rownum`.

Here is my current query where it will retrieve 2nd and 4th row:

```
SELECT * FROM Record a
WHERE
2 = (SELECT COUNT (rowid)
              FROM Record b
             WHERE a.rowid >= b.rowid)

UNION 

SELECT * FROM Record a
WHERE
4 = (SELECT COUNT (rowid)
              FROM Record c
             WHERE a.rowid >= c.rowid);
```

Maybe there are other better ways to do it? TQ

Comment: Why can't you use ROWNUM?

Comment: 2nd and 4th ordered by what?

Comment: Your need is not that clear to me. Can you please post some sample data and needed result?

Comment: there is no relationship between ROWID and 'order' of data or rows in a table - the ordering of rows is never guaranteed unless you also have an ORDER BY in your query

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thats the task condition. not allowed to use row number

Comment: oracle 10g @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @user6308605 Some kind of homework assignment then? Your question uses inconsistent wording; do you want the "2nd until 4th" rows (i.e. rows 2, 3 and 4) or the "2nd and 4th" rows (i.e. rows 2 and 4)?

Comment: I want from 2nd row to 4th row (2,3,4). I was just showing my current logic to get 2nd and 4th rows. @AnthonyGrist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid `rownum` and `row_number`, use `sum`:

```
select *
from (
        select sum(1) over ( order by rowid /* or whatever you need */ ) as rn,
               r.*
          from record
     )
where rn between 2 and 4
```

The trick is only in the fact that here `sum(1)` gives the same thing than `count(1)` or `count(rowid)` or whatever `count` on a `not null` value, and this is the same thing than counting the rows with `row_number` or `rownum`.
In this way you use the `sum` to compute a `row_number`, without explicitly writing '`row_number`' or '`rownum`'.

```
SQL> create table testTab(x) as ( select level from dual connect by level <= 6);

Table created.

SQL> select t.*,
  2         count(1)     over (order by rowid desc) as count,
  3         sum(1)       over (order by rowid desc) as sum,
  4         row_number() over (order by rowid desc) as rowNumber
  5  from testTab t;

         X      COUNT        SUM  ROWNUMBER
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         6          1          1          1
         5          2          2          2
         4          3          3          3
         3          4          4          4
         2          5          5          5
         1          6          6          6
```

The external query simply applies the filter.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use `rownum`, then use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowid) as seqnum
      FROM Record a
     ) a
WHERE seqnum BETWEEN 2 and 4;
```

Note:  The `??` is for an ordering column.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no concept of a first row or a second row, except in reference to an ordering column.  You can use `rowid` for this purpose.

In Oracle 12c, you would use `OFFSET`/`FETCH`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Record a
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

I should point out that you *can* use rownum.  You just can't do:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Record a
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 2 and 4;
```

You can use it in a subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum as seqnum
      FROM Record a
     ) a
WHERE seqnum BETWEEN 2 and 4;
```

Do note that without an `ORDER BY`, there is no guarantee that the results come back in any order, including `rowid` order.

Comment: for this task, im not allowed to use rownum. and im using oracle 10g

Comment: @user6308605  then use `row_number()`

Comment: To be honest, it says DO NOT USE ROW NUMBER . Not specific if `rownum` or `row_number()` But Ill just answer anyway. Been stuck for hours. Thank you sooo much! @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle 12c, you can now easily do row limiting. In your scenario you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM RECORD
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM RECORD
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```